# No such host exist using Dns.GetHostEntry

Tags: c#, dns

When i try to get request client machine name using

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(
    Request.ServerVariables("remote_addr")
).HostName.Split(New [Char]() {"."c}) ,
```

then it gives me below error

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
```

can any one please help me.

Answer (score 1):

a remote_addr ( client ip address ) entry in your server environment is not guaranteed to have a corresponding DNS entry.

Even if the address had an entry, the dns entry for the address might not be in the server DNS catalog and the server might have not found the entry via recursive lookup.